# Для чего в тестировании использовать when()?

Tags: android, junit

Вот читаю [офф док](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html#build) и тут приводиться такой пример

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UnitTestSample {

private static final String FAKE_STRING = "HELLO WORLD";

@Mock
Context mMockContext;

@Test
public void readStringFromContext_LocalizedString() {
    // Given a mocked Context injected into the object under test...
    when(mMockContext.getString(R.string.hello_word))
            .thenReturn(FAKE_STRING);
    ClassUnderTest myObjectUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(mMockContext);

    // ...when the string is returned from the object under test...
    String result = myObjectUnderTest.getHelloWorldString();

    // ...then the result should be the expected one.
    assertThat(result, is(FAKE_STRING));
}
}
```

насколько я понимаю в строке где `when()` написано, попробуй получить стринг и присвой его переменной `FAKE_STRING` ...

Но тогда не понятно зачем вообще этот `when()`

Чтобы поменялось в данном коде если бы из него удалили эту строку

```
when(mMockContext.getString(R.string.hello_word)).thenReturn(FAKE_STRING);
```

**ПРАВКА**

Вот так должен выглядеть класс

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class EmailValidatorTest {

private static final String FAKE_STRING = "hello world";

@Mock Context mMockContext;

@Test
public void readStringFromContext_LocalizedString() {
// Given a mocked Context injected into the object under test...
when(mMockContext.getString(R.string.hello_word)).thenReturn(FAKE_STRING);

EmailValidator myObjectUnderTest = new EmailValidator(mMockContext);

// ...when the string is returned from the object under test...
String result = myObjectUnderTest.getHelloWorldString();

String matcher = mMockContext.getString(R.string.hello_word);
// ...then the result should be the expected one.
assertThat(result, is(matcher));
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почитайте документацию для фреймворка Mockito.

В частности ваш код с `when().return()` означает что когда на объекте `mMockContext` вызовут метод `getString()` с параметром `R.string.hello_word`, то данный метод должен вернуть `FAKE_STRING`

Т.е с данным фреймворком вы можете контролировать что будут возвращать методы объекта, когда они будут вызываться с теми или иными параметрами. Это надо тогда, когда вы хотите протестировать какой то объект, который зависит от другого объекта. И для того, что бы контролировать эту зависимость вы подменяете его фейковым объектом, методы которого будут возвращать то, что вам надо. Тем самым вы сможете спрогнозировать ожидаемый результат и проверит его.

Comment: Я добавил в вопрос правку. я так понимаю, что вот так должен выглядеть класс чтоб все было логично связано? А то получается что в первом примере устанавливается  возвратное значение, но в итоге мы берем его из константы...  не логично как то

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko нет, правильнее первый вариант, ведь надо сравнивать результат работы класса с заранее известным правильным вариантом, а во втором варианте вы сравниваете результат работы класса фактические с тем же результатом.

Comment: все ясно) Все обькты которые будут пользоваться этим контектстом будут и будут вызывать на нем этот стринг будут получать значение которое мы задаем...